# What does $P\Longleftrightarrow Q$ mean and what is the truth table for it?

Tags: logic

I see the the truth table for $\text{if}\ P, \text{then}\ Q$. What does this mean when I see this in an example and what is the truth table for it?

$$P\Longleftrightarrow Q$$

I have no clue what this means like I said. I have seen question similar to it with $P\implies Q$, but nothing to what I am asking.

Comment: Have you ever seen "if P then Q" written as $P\implies Q$? If so, then you might take a wild guess at what $P\iff Q$ means.

Answer (score 1):

That symbol is for the biconditional, which, rather than being an "if $p$ then $q$", is a "$p$ if and only if $q$", meaning the truth table is going to be true if $p$ and $q$ are the same, and false is $p$ and $q$ are different.

In other words, it is essentially a two way if statement. That is, "if $p$ then $q$" AND "if $q$ then $p$".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_biconditional

Answer (score 0):

$P\Longleftrightarrow Q$ means that $P$ and $Q$ are logically equivalent. In other words, $P$ implies $Q$ **and** $Q$ implies $P$.